# Show Toolbar shadow only on scroll in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I would like to know how I can use a Toolbar / CollapsingToolbarLayout in a CoordinatorLayout to show a shadow only when content is scrolled under it and not otherwise (i.e. after the fragment is created it should not show a shadow until the user starts scrolling down a list). Preferably with just XML

(I don't think I need a AppBarLayout here, since the size of the toolbar is fixed and does not need the resizing or parallax effects etc..)

Any help with this is much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android toolbar elevation when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724308/android-toolbar-elevation-when-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting elevation of the toolbar.
0 elevation means no shadow.

`toolbar.setElevation(int)`

Comment: I do want the elevation when content is being scrolled (also preferably in XML)

Comment: You can again call `setElevation()` when the user scrolls. Maybe put it in list's onScrollListener.